# Dart - abstract class with a factory and its children

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two class in my flutter app:

```
 class ChildrenA{
     ....
     factory ChildrenA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChildrenA(
            x: json["x"],
            y: json["y"],
     );
 }

class ChildrenB{
     ....
     factory ChildrenA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChildrenB(
            x1: json["x1"],
            y2: json["y2"],
     );
 }
```

Can I add a parent class for these two? more or less like this

```
   abstract class Parent{
     factory Parent.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json);
   }
```

is it possible in dart? or other ways - using mixin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited, so probably no.